# Why does this mute function show all the hidden channels?

Tags: discord.js

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
                channel.overwritePermissions([
                    {
                        id: muteRole.id,
                        deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'CONNECT', 'ADD_REACTIONS'],
                    },
                ], 'Mute role permissions');
            });
```

This shows all hidden channels and resets all permissions in all channels.

Comment: You are filtering every channel in a guild, Try finding a specific channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `overwritePermissions()` like it says overwrites every permission, 
you can use `updateOverwrite()` instead

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite

```js
message.channel.updateOverwrite(muteRole.id, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: false
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped, I knew I should've checked docs more often.